# Converting IplImage to osg::Image

Tags: opencv, openscenegraph

How can I correctly convert an OpenCV IplImage to OpenSceneGraph's osg::Image?

This my current method. But I'm getting incorrect color data.

```
// IplImage* cvImg is a webcam output image captured using cvQueryFrame(capture)
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> osgImage = new osg::Image;
osgImage->setImage(cvImg->width,cvImg->height, 3,
                           GL_RGB, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                           (BYTE*)(cvImg->imageData),
                           osg::Image::AllocationMode::NO_DELETE,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an issue involving OpenCV's native BGR color space. You don't mention which version of OpenCV you are using, but modern versions define `CV_BGR2RGB` for use with [cvCvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvcvtcolor#void%20cvCvtColor%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20int%20code%29). Possibly doing the conversion like this

```
IplImage* pImg = cvLoadImage("lines.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cvCvtColor(pImg, pImg, CV_BGR2RGB);
cvReleaseImage(&pImg);
```

If you can't use that another option would be use [cvSplit](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsplit#void%20cvSplit%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst0,%20CvArr%2a%20dst1,%20CvArr%2a%20dst2,%20CvArr%2a%20dst3%29) to separate and reorder the channels and then combine them with [cvMerge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsplit#void%20merge%28const%20Mat%2a%20mv,%20size_t%20count,%20OutputArray%20dst%29).

On a side note, I would definitely recommend using the C++ interface as it is much easier memory management, and has more features than the C interface.

Hope that helps!